# Get gmail messages using javascript - atom feed not working

Tags: javascript, http, web, feed, atom-feed

I'm trying to access the gmail atom feed but can't seem to get it working. I've tried:

```
function testing(){
    alert("hi");
    getMail = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getMail.open('GET','https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/feed/atom/', true);
    getMail.onload = function() { 
        var allXML = getMail.responseText;
        alert("hi2");
        alert(allXML);
    }
    getMail.send(null);
}
```

But when I run it I can't see the "hi2", let along the response text.
I am logged on to gmail and can see the xml if I put `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/feed/atom/'` directly into the browser. I'm using Firefox v29.

I've read the previous similar questions on here but nothing has helped.

## Edit

Now I get to the "hi2" but the responseText is blank... code is:

```
function testing(){
        getMail = new XMLHttpRequest();
        getMail.open('GET','https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/feed/atom/', true);
        getMail.withCredentials = true; 
        getMail.onreadystatechange = function() { 
                if (getMail.readyState == 4) {
                    var allXML = getMail.responseText;
                    alert("hi2");
                    alert(allXML);
                }
            }
            getMail.send(null);
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: From what kind of origin are you running this? Is this another website? A browser extension? My guess is that you're running into the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: @thejh, At the moment I'm serving the page locally as it's in development but ultimately I might host it somewhere. If it is SOP, what can I do about it? Thanks.